# Python Regular Expressions; Having 0 match either 0 or 1

Tags: python, regex

I have a shorter string `s` I'm trying to match to a longer string `s1.` 1's match 1's, but 0's will match either a 0 or a 1.

For instance:

```
s = '11111' would match s1 = '11111'

s = '11010' would match s1 = '11111' or '11011' or '11110' or '11010'
```

I know regular expressions would make this much easier but am confused on where to start.

Comment: You say "a longer string s1", but all your examples have the same length. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 6):

Replace each instance of `0` with `[01]` to enable it matching either `0` or `1`:

```
s = '11010'
pattern = s.replace('0', '[01]')
regex = re.compile(pattern)

regex.match('11111')
regex.match('11011')
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you're actually looking for bit arithmetics

```
s = '11010'
n = int(s, 2)
for r in ('11111', '11011', '11110', '11010'):
    if int(r, 2) & n == n:
        print r, 'matches', s
    else:
        print r, 'doesnt match', s
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def matches(pat, s):
    p  = re.compile(pat.replace('0', '[01]') + '$')
    return p.match(s) is not None

print matches('11111', '11111')
print matches('11111', '11011')
print matches('11010', '11111')
print matches('11010', '11011')
```

You say "match to a *longer* string s1", but you don't say whether you'd like to match the start of the string, or the end etc. Until I better understand your requirements, this performs an exact match.